# txt file wont load by using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to implement an ajax with simple txt file but the file won't load any suggestion

the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<script src="app.js"></script>

<title>Ajax 1 - Text File</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button" onclick="loadText()">Get Text File</button>

</body>
</html>
```

and the javascript file:

```
//Create event Listener of the Get Text File 


function loadText(){
// Create XHR object
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// OPEN - type, url/fileName, async
//console.log(xhr);
xhr.open('GET', 'sample.txt', true);

xhr.onload = function(){

    //HTTP statuses
    //200: OK
    //403: Forbiden
    //404: Not Found

    if(this.status == 200){
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
    //Send Request
    xhr.send();
}
}
```

and this is the sample.txt file

```
This massage form the text file just to ensure you have the ability to 
access the text file. so if you do good for you otherwise just keep 
trying
```

Note, I'm trying to achieve it using vanilla javascript without any frameworks or library

As an output I get nothing once I click the button and even in the network tab in the inspector the txt file never even load.

[image]

Note, I'm using live sever on vscode

Comment: Trying moving `xhr.send();` outside of the `onload` method.

Comment: use anchor tag and its `download` attribute

Comment: @brk thanks for the help Vladimir Bogomolov comments work.

Comment: but is it suppose to be inside the the the onload function how come once I move it out it works

Comment: @AbdallahRizk `onload` is the event that fires when the request is completed. Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/bg/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xhr.send() should be outside xhr.onload()

xhr.onload() is the callback function to be executed when the request completes successfully.

refer the docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload

```js
and the javascript file:

//Create event Listener of the Get Text File 


function loadText(){
// Create XHR object
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // OPEN - type, url/fileName, async
  //console.log(xhr);
  xhr.open('GET', 'sample.txt', true);

  xhr.onload = function(){

      //HTTP statuses
      //200: OK
      //403: Forbiden
      //404: Not Found

      if(this.status == 200){
          console.log(this.responseText);
      }
      //Send Request
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<script src="app.js"></script>

<title>Ajax 1 - Text File</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button" onclick="loadText()">Get Text File</button>

</body>
</html>
```